# getting type error on occasion but not every time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am building an e-commerce site.  Right now it's basically one HTML page that filters in based on page loads and clicks.  I did it this because the entire site needed to be dynamic, as I'll be tying in a show shortly.

Everything seems to work fine now that I have placed the script on the actual pages instead of in a main .js file.  I get a few hiccups here and there, and I'm hoping this issue will help fix some of them.

Sometimes when I click on the view cart button it throws back a type error saying that $a.mobile.document.on is not a function.  This doesn't happen all the time.  I can just click the button with the shopping cart open and the cart just refreshes.  As I am clicking the button, nothing in the code should be changing, everything should be flowing the exact same.  Why do I get the error sometimes? There is no pattern as to how often the error occurs (i.e. every 3rd click, etc...)

My code:

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>DATique</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jqm-icon-pack-fa.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container" data-role="page" data-theme="b">

        <div id="header" data-role="header">

            <div id="headerGraphic"><img class="menu" src="img/products/DATique.png" alt="" align=center></div>
            <!-- todo add tagline back in -->
            <div data-role="footer" id="headerTagLine">an adult novelty company</div>
        </div>

        <div id="mainNavBar">
            <div id="mainNav" data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="home ui-icon-home">Home</li>
                    <li class="about ui-icon-question-circle">About</li>
                    <li class="contact ui-icon-envelope">Contact</li>
                    <li class="request ui-icon-lightbulb-o">Requests</li>
                    <li class="find ui-icon-location-arrow">Find</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content" data-role="main">

            <!-- todo add facebook plugin -->
            <div id="sideBar">
                <div id="sideNav">
                    <script>

                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="productWindow">
                <script>

                </script>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" id="footer">
            <ul>
                <li id="addingItem"></li>
                <li id="cartHolder">
                    <div class="view">View Cart</div>
                    <div class="cartImg"><img src="lib/png/shopping-cart.png"></div>
                    <div class="badge ui-corner-all"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var initialLoad = $.post('lib/aboutUs.php');
            initialLoad.done(function (data) {
                $('#productWindow').html(data);
            });

            var sideBar = $.post('lib/sideNav.php');
            sideBar.done(function (data) {
                $('#sideNav').html(data);
            });

            $('#cartHolder').unbind().click(function (data) {
                var url = 'lib/cart.php';
                var getCart = $.post(url);
                console.log(data);
                getCart.done(function (data) {
                    $('#content').html(data);
                });
                getCart.fail(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            });

        })
    </script>
    </body>
```

Here's my cart.php. The only file affected by the click event is the show cart button.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 

    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 



<?php
session_start();  
#$_SESSION = array();  

$items = $_SESSION;  


echo "<div id='showCart' class='ui-corner-all' style='max-width:400px;'>  
    <div data-role='header' data-theme='a' class='ui-corner-all' style='margin-top:20px;'>  
    <h1>Your Cart</h1>  
    </div>  
    <div role='main' class='ui-content ui-corner-all'>  

        <ul data-role='listview' data-split-icon='delete' data-split-theme='d'>";  
foreach ($items['cart'] as $list) {  
    echo "<li ><a href='#'>  
                <img src = 'img/products/" . $list['itemNum'] . ".png'>  
                <h3 > " . $list['itemName'] . " </h3 >  
                <h1 style='text-align:right'> " . $list['price'] . "   
</h1 ></a>
                <a href='#' class='removeItem' name='" . $list['itemNum'] . "'>Remove Item</a>                                 
            </li >";  
}  

echo "</ul>          
      </div>  
      </div>"  
?>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {  
    console.log ("error ready");  
    function showCart() {  
        console.log("showCart Function");  

        var url = 'lib/cart.php';  
        var getCart = $.post(url);  
        getCart.done(function (data) {  
            console.log("cart received");  
            $('#content').html(data);  
        });  
    }  

    $('.removeItem').unbind().click(function () {   
        console.log("remove clicked");  
        var itemNum = {'itemNum': ($(this).attr('name'))};  
        var sent = $.post("lib/removeFromCart.php", itemNum);  

        sent.done(function () {  
            console.log("item removed from cart");  
                showCart();  
        });  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

I also have 2 other pages that have script on them that are loaded onto the home page by $.post.

Sorry if this question is easy, I just hope it isn't a period or brace somewhere. It's almost always a period or a brace.  Again, looking to see if someone can tell me why this sometimes throws an error when I hit the view cart button.  It seems to be doing it right after the console.log call in the cart.php.

Comment: why are you reloading js files in your `cart.php`? are the scripts not loaded in the main page?

Comment: that's how i orginally had this set up.  i had all my javascript in a myScript.js file that loaded at the bottom of the html of the main page.  but none of the other pages with scipts would read the javascript on the main page for some reason until i loaded the .js file into each page.  but then i was getting a synchronous function deprecation error, so i took them all out and put them on their original pages.  does this cause a problem with the way i have it now

Comment: whats this for `$('#cartHolder').unbind().click(`  if you are adding content dynamically you should be using `on(` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note not an answer

> i had all my javascript in a myScript.js file that loaded at the bottom of the html of the main page. but none of the other pages with scipts would read the javascript on the main page for some reason until i loaded the .js file into each page.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  code 1
....});

 $(document).ready(function() { 
  code 2
....});
```

code 1 is not able to access code 2 and vice versa, in php this is akin to this

```
function one(){
     code 1
} 

function too(){
    code 2
}
```

One way around that is to globalize stuff, by using `window.` although it's not usually recommended.

```
    var one;

    var window.one;
```

for example( scope resolution ).  Other ways involve using the DOM, by attaching to a object on the page, such as how a plugin works. for example using `$(element).data('mydata', {foo:'bar'});`

not sure if this was what you were saying but the explanation is way to long for a comment.